# How to do pagination by using array with out using any plungin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used `pagination` by showing and hiding 10 results. 
but what I want is this should be done through an `array`. If I `click` next page the 10 values should be load from `array`.

All the array elements are getting loaded initially itself but i want to load 10 results each time on selecting the page numbers like (1, 2, 3 etc.,) ie., At a time the **ul** should have only 10 li loaded. [all li should not be inside the ul ]

please help me out in this.

Here fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3qu7u4ej/13/

**Script**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    /* search results data */
    var searchResults = [
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'},
        {'searchHeader' : 'Lorem Ipsum - Dolor Sit Amet',
        'searchResult' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dapibus ex vel nulla rhoncus viverra. Proin sed erat vel purus suscipit ultrices sed in ipsum. Aenean leo ut vestibulum posuere.',
        'searchType' : 'Article',
        'searchDate' : 'Posted: MM/DD/YYYY'}

    ]

    /* search results data display */
    for(var i=0; i<searchResults.length; i++){
        $('.search-results--display').append('<li><p class="search-results--header">'+i+'&nbsp;'+searchResults[i].searchHeader+'</p>'+searchResults[i].searchResult+'<p class="search-results--info"><span class="search-results--type">'+searchResults[i].searchType+'</span><span class="search-results--date">Posted: '+searchResults[i].searchDate+'</span></p></li>');         
    }
    var show_per_page = 10;
    pagination = function(page,show_per_page){
            var number_of_items = $('#paginate li').size();
            var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items / show_per_page);
            var number_of_pages_todisplay = 5;
            var navigation_html = '';
            var current_page = page;
            var current_link = (number_of_pages_todisplay >= current_page ? 1 : number_of_pages_todisplay + 1);
            if (current_page > 1)
                current_link = current_page;
            if (current_link != 1)
                navigation_html += "<li class='firstbutton'><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:first();\">Start</a></li><li><a class='prevbutton paginationButton' href=\"javascript:previous();\">Prev&nbsp;</a></li>";
            if (current_link == number_of_pages - 1) 
                current_link = current_link - 3;
            else if (current_link == number_of_pages)
                current_link = current_link - 4;
            else if (current_link > 2)
                current_link = current_link - 2;
            else 
                current_link = 1;
            var pages = number_of_pages_todisplay;
            while (pages != 0) {
                if (number_of_pages < current_link) {
                    break;
                }
                if (current_link >= 1)
                    navigation_html += "<li><a class='paginationButton " + ((current_link == current_page) ? "currentPageButton" : "numericButton") + "' href=\"javascript:showPage(" + current_link + ","+show_per_page+")\" longdesc='" + current_link + "'>" + (current_link) + "</a></li>";
                current_link++;
                pages--;
            }
            if (number_of_pages > current_page){
                navigation_html += "<li><a class='nextbutton paginationButton' href=\"javascript:next()\">Next</a></li><li class='lastbutton'><a class='nextbutton' href=\"javascript:last(" + number_of_pages + ");\">Last</a></li>";
            }
            $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);
      }

        var pageSize = 10;

        showPage = function (page,show_per_page) {
            /*var current_page_number = parseInt($('#current_page').val())+1);
            $.extend(searchResultsCopy,searchResults);
            searchResults.slice(
            $('.search-results--display').html()*/
            $("#paginate li").hide();
            $('#current_page').val(page);
            $("#paginate li").each(function (n) {
                if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                    $(this).show();
            });
            pagination(page,show_per_page);
       }
       showPage(1,10);
       next = function () {
            new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
            showPage(new_page,show_per_page);
        }
        last = function (number_of_pages) {
            new_page = number_of_pages;
            $('#current_page').val(new_page);
            showPage(new_page,show_per_page);
        }
        first = function () {
            var new_page = "1";
            $('#current_page').val(new_page);
            showPage(new_page,show_per_page);    
        }
        previous = function () {
            new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
            $('#current_page').val(new_page);
            showPage(new_page,show_per_page);
        }

        $('.search-results--results-per-page a').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.search-results--results-per-page a').removeClass('currentPageButton');
            $(this).addClass('currentPageButton');
            if($(this).hasClass('display-20'))
                pageSize = 20;
            else if($(this).hasClass('display-50'))
                pageSize = 50;
            else if($(this).hasClass('display-all'))
                pageSize = $(".search-results--display li").length;
            else
                pageSize = 10;
            showPage(1,pageSize);           
        });
});
```

Comment: I think the values are getting loaded from an array only. The searchResults array.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your fiddle!!

Comment: All the array elements are getting loaded initially itself but i want to load 10 results each time on selecting the page numbers like (1, 2, 3 etc.,) ie., At a time the **ul** should have only 10 li loaded. [all li should not be inside the ul ]

Comment: What is your problem in doing so? I think you should specify your question.

Comment: @wiktus239 when i click the pagination all the values are getting loaded in li. I want only selecting page should load the 10 li. not all the li.

Comment: I understand what you want. What seems to be the problem in doing so tho?

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends i got the answer for this question, Thanks for your responds

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pak2ytnb/

**HTML**

```
  <div class="search-results">
<div class="search-results--display" id="paginate">
    <!-- search results will be displayed here -->
</div>

<!-- pagination div for mobile and ipad-->
<div class="search-results--pagination-rep-ipad">
    <span class="search-results--left-res icon-arrow-blue-left-1x"></span>
    <p class="search-results--prev"><span class="icon-arrow-blue-left-1x"></span><span class="pagination-text">Prev</span></p>
    <p class="search-results--curr">Page 2 of 10</p>
    <p class="search-results--next"><span class="pagination-text">Next</span><span class="icon-arrow-blue-right-1x"></span></p>
    <span class="search-results--right-res icon-arrow-blue-right-1x"></span>
</div>
<!-- responsive pagination div ends here-->

<div class="search-results--pagination">
    <ul class="search-results--pages" id='page_navigation'>
        <!-- pagination rendered dynamically through script-->
    </ul>
    <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />

    <ul class="search-results--results-per-page">
        <li>Results per page:</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="display-10 paginationButton currentPageButton">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="display-20 paginationButton">20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="display-50 paginationButton">50</a></li>
        <li class="view-all-results"><a href="#" class="paginationButton     display-all">View All</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```